# Laravel 5.5 multiple image upload

Tags: php, laravel, dropzone

I try to use dropzoneJS in order to upload multiple image for my products and so far I can save images in database, also in images folder but I have problem with getting product id to relate each image to products.

> Here is what I have:

## Databases

1. Products (where my products including info will save)
2. Images (where my images including product id will save *screenshot provided* )

[image: images db]

## Models

**Product:**

```
public function images()
  {
    return $this->morphMany(Image::class, 'imageable');
  }
```

**Image:**

```
class Image extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = ['name'];


  public function imageable()
  {
      return $this->morphTo();
  }

  public function product()
  {
  return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
  }
}
```

## Image Schema

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('imageable_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('imageable_type')->nullable();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

## ImageController

```
class ImageController extends Controller
{
  public function dropzone()
  {
    return view('dropzone-view');
  }

  public function dropzoneStore(Request $request)
  {
    // works
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $filename = 'product' . '-' . time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $filePath = public_path('images/');
    $request->file('file')->move($filePath, $filename);

    return Image::create([
      'name' => $filename,
      'imageable_id' => $request->input('imageable_id'),
    ])->id;

  }

}
```

## Product Create (Blade)

```
// Form
{!! Form::open([ 'route' => [ 'dropzone.store' ], 'files' => true, 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'class' => 'dropzone mt-20', 'id' => 'my-awesome-dropzone' ]) !!}
 <div class="fallback">
   <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
 </div>
 <input type="hidden" name="imageIds[]" value="">
{{Form::close()}}

// Javascript
<script type="text/javascript">
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("form#my-awesome-dropzone", {
  headers: {
    "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content")
  },
  acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
  dictDefaultMessage: "Drag an image here to upload, or click to select one",
  maxFiles: 15, // Maximum Number of Files
  maxFilesize: 8, // MB
  addRemoveLinks: true,
});

myDropzone.on("success", function (response) {console.log(response.xhr.response); });

</script>
```

Any idea?

Comment: I don't see any mention of product ID in your image upload form.

Comment: @TanjaForsberg that's the thing i got here so far by help of others in most part and he stopped helping! so i stuck halfway.

Comment: Ok. Working of the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Code for controller:

```
class ImageController extends Controller
{
  public function dropzone($id)
  {
$product = Product::find($id);
return view('dropzone-view')
      ->withProduct($porduct);
}
  public function dropzoneStore(Request $request)
  {
// works
$file = $request->file('file');
$filename = 'product' . '-' . time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$filePath = public_path('images/');
$request->file('file')->move($filePath, $filename);

return Image::create([
  'name' => $filename,
  'imageable_id' => $request->input('imageable_id'),
])->id;
  }
}
```

Code on blade view:

```
{!! Form::open([ 'route' => [ 'dropzone.store' ], 'files' => true, 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'class' => 'dropzone mt-20', 'id' => 'my-awesome-dropzone' ]) !!}
 <div class="fallback">
  <input name="imageable_id" type="hidden" value="{{$product->id}}" />
<input name="file" type="file" multiple />
 </div>
{{Form::close()}}
```

Try this hope this should get you going. This is one of many way to make this thing work.

Comment: here is an issue:  `<input name="imageable_id" type="hidden" value="{{$product->id}}" />` i am on create product page there is no `product->id` till i save it.

Comment: Oh. So you are uploading images on product create page ??

Comment: I suggest you to do it on separate view i.e product.show view. As you are aware that dopzone uploads files via ajax and before attaching product ID with Images. Products must me created first.

Comment: that is a way but not meaningful way! that way my product will be published without image till i upload images later! take wordpress as sample we can open gallery as popup and upload images then save both images and post/product at once, that's what i try to do here

Comment: idea: what if we put `Image::create([` part in product store method before `$product->save()` ? in that case we will only use one form (product store form) and save images before saving product?  is that possible?

Comment: Stil how are you going to fill `imageable_id` on product images table ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162474/discussion-between-tanja-forsberg-and-mafortis).

Comment: hi there, how are you? should we finish what we started? :)

Answer (score 0):

this is a morpic relation and this is how you get morphic relation

```
$post = App\Post::find(1);

foreach ($post->comments as $comment) {
    //
}
```

read about it here [polymorphic-relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations)

Answer (score 0):

What i normally do is,

1. After you upload a picture, return the ID of the newly created image (you already do that in ImageController)
2. On your product page, in the dropzone 'success' callback you can read the the image ID and add it to an hidden array input field
3. In your controller you have to create the new product, and then after saving it , you can attach the images to the correct product, because now you have the id's of the images + the product instance has been made.